# Bad request when deploying smart contract

Tags: multiversx

So I'm currently trying to deploy a router smart contract. I've been building it through `erdpy contract build`, which has been successful (I'm on rust nightly tool chain as the Smart contract needs it). And I am now trying to deploy it, but I can't manage to do it. I keep having a `400 BadRequest` from `https://devnet-api.elrond.com/transaction/send`.

Here are the logs from the deployment:

```
erdpy contract deploy
INFO:accounts:Account.sync_nonce()
INFO:accounts:Account.sync_nonce() done: 0
INFO:cli.contracts:Contract address: erd1qqqqqqqqqqqqqpgqzqv7kk893c3ftwgaekvvv9whpqcfn4kazqxq3mud36
INFO:transactions:Transaction.send: nonce=0
CRITICAL:cli:Proxy request error for url [https://devnet-api.elrond.com/transaction/send]: {'statusCode': 400, 'message': 'Bad Request'}
```

And here is `erdpy.json` used to configure the command:

```
{
    "configurations": {
        "default": {
            "proxy": "https://devnet-api.elrond.com",
            "chainID": "D"
        }
    },
    "contract":{
        "deploy":{
            "verbose": true,
            "bytecode": "output/router.wasm",
            "recall-nonce": true,
            "nonce": 1,
            "pem": "../../../wallets/owner/wallet-owner.pem",
            "gas-limit": 600000000,
            "send": true,
            "outfile": "deploy-testnet.interaction.json"
        }
    }
}
```

The contract I'm trying to deploy is the [following](https://github.com/ElrondNetwork/sc-dex-rs/tree/main/dex/router). I've also been through the [OpenAPI Spec](https://api-docs.elrond.com/) or the [documentation](https://docs.elrond.com/sdk-and-tools/rest-api/transactions/#estimate-cost-of-transaction) searching for an answer, but there is nothing about it. This route is normally returning error message, but for this specific case it is not.

Some other contract like `ping-pong` are working properly with the same `erdpy.json` config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking with someone who were interested into this issue, I ended up with the following command:

`erdpy --verbose contract deploy --project=$PROJECT_NAME --pem="wallet-owner.pem" --gas-limit=600000000 --proxy="https://devnet-gateway.elrond.com" --outfile="elrond.workspace.json" --recall-nonce --send --chain="D"`

Replace `$PROJECT_NAME` by the folder of your contract (you need to be one level upper than your smart contract folder).

It won't use the `elrond.json` file, but i guess you can move up the file to make the command use it.

Answer (score 1):

I have you tried to deploy with the argument `--verbose`?

That should be something like that (not sure of the syntax because I am on phone)
`erdpy --verbose contract deploy`

Comment: Yes, in fact if you look into the configuration I gave you can see it in `.contract.deploy.verbose`. The logs I gave are already in verbose. Moreover, I tried the HTTP request manually (from postman), and it gave the same answer: a bad request without much information.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the "bad request" error too, and I worked out that for me this was because my wallet was empty. To add xEGLD to your devnet wallet:

1. Go to https://devnet-wallet.elrond.com/faucet
2. Log in using your pem file / whatever you normally use to log in
3. Click the "Faucet" option from the left hand menu
4. This should pop up a modal to add 10 xEGLD to your wallet (You can request 10 xEGLD every 24 hours)
5. Now you can return to the terminal and run `erdpy contract deploy`

This worked for me, and now I'm getting the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

In the suggested `erdpy.json` from Elrond Docs there is an `"chainID": "D"` variable inside `configuration.default` object.

Delete this and add inside `contract.deploy` this : `"chain": "D"`.

### Example

```
{
  "configurations": {
    "default": {
      "proxy": "https://devnet-api.elrond.com"
      "chainID": "D" <----- Delete this
    }
  },
  "contract":{
    "deploy":{
      <Other fields>
      "chain": "D" <----- Add this
    }
  }
}
```